# infragistics controls vs asp.net controls - performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, infragistics

Any performance comparision between asp.net controls and infragistics controls? I need to compare all controls e.g. TextBox, DropDownList etc.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the trial versions and testing them yourself?

Comment: Actually, creating performance matrix for each available control takes lots of time. If someone already has that comparision, why should I re-invent wheel? Hope this makes sense !

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. And you may need to clarify what performance you mean...possibilities include:

- Server side performance (perhaps databinding)
- Actual bandwidth (amount of html and extra scripts/styles/images etc) required
- Client side performance (events and what not)
- post backs? ajax?

It would be quite hard to do performance comparisons because it depends a lot on what features you require of the controls. Some of the Infragistics web controls now give you the option of only loading the javascript for features that you will use as well which would complicate things...I suppose also, a lot of the third party controls exist because there isn't an asp.net default equivalent.

You really perhaps need to try the controls, or set a target level of performance and measure whether it meets this...the asp.net may well perform faster but both meet your performance requirements...or expectedly don't meet your performance requirements but provide you more features...